# How to show a error on client side after validation on server side in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, validation

I am fairly new to django. I want to check user entered value for the price value input in my web page, against all values in my existing database while doing server side validation.
I am using django forms. my database have fields called "name" and "price". I want add user input to data base if user entered price value is larger than the all existing price values in my database. otherwise i want to show an error on the client side like "enter a larger value". 
This is what I have came up with so far.

This is my form in views.py

```
class myform (forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price= forms.IntegerField( validators = [MinValueValidator(0,0)], widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min' : 0}))
```

I am trying to validate it in here

```
    def add_item (request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            max_price = items.objects.order_by("-price").first().price
            if request.POST["price"] < max_price:
                return render(request,"myapp/items.html")
            else:
                items.objects.create(name = request.POST["name"] , price = request.POST["price"]) 
                return render(request,"myapp/index.html")
```

I tried to use validators to show message on the client side but it was not succefull. because I couldn't figured out how to use database entries in validation methods to raise validation errors.

Comment: How do you display the form on the html ?

Comment: I use code like this to pass form to the template
`return render(request,"market/listing.html",{
                "form":NewformClass(),
                 })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use 'AJAX' calls, to validate the price in server side(without having to submit the form), and if the price were to not meet your requirements you could , return an error saying 'please enter a new value' .

Furthermore , since you have not given any sort of html input , using the minimum knowledge we have, I'll suggest that you disable the button (by default) , that submits the form until the validation is done, this can be done with the help of a variable returned from the ajax call

Reference link: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Steps made simple:

1.Disable submit button by default

2.Create ajax call

3.Validate ajax call, if price is satisfying condition , then enable submit button

4.Submit the form and enter the new price in your database

Sample Ajax call:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "/your_url_for_ajax_function",
        data:{
                 price: priceinput            //priceinput is the value which 
                                                you get from the input field
        },
        success: function( data ) 
        {
            //Add the error part over here , and enable the submit button
        }
     })
```

Furthermore, I would also suggest creating another views.py(with a different name) for ajax calls alone, otherwise your main views.py could get extremely long and functions could be very hard to find (btw there is no issue with having different sorts of functions in the same view, this tip is just for ease of searching and editing , down the line)

You could also search up several videos, on youtube , incase the link seems to hard to understand

Good luck!

Comment: Okay. thank you very much..! I will look in to it

Comment: If it works, do accept the ans ,and upvote it , much appreciated